# List all columns in a nested json using pyspark?

Tags: json, pyspark

Read a below json file and list all columns using pyspark.

**Ex: input JSON**

```
{"_abc":"test","A":{"A1":"123","A2":{"A21":"123","A22":"234"}}
```

**Output:**

**List of Columns:**

```
_abc

A.A1

A.A2.A21

A.A2.A22
```

Comment: I didn't understand very well, you want to know how to have this specific Output for the example input ? Can you explain more please?

Comment: yes. I need to find all the columns in a JSON with dot notation of end node.